# Creating and handling an encrypted folder on sd-card for unrooted devices

Tags: sd-card, encryption

I'm looking for a way to create an encrypted folder on the sd-card and provide password protected access to its contents. Ideally, this would provide a UI to encrypt new files by moving files to it and retrieve them back.

I know there is [EncFS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=csh.cryptonite) but it only works in rooted devices.
And also [BoxCryptor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boxcryptor.android&feature=also_installed) which is only for Google Drive or DropBox.

I need a solution which would work with sd-card folders and on unrooted devices.

Comment: See also these previous similar questions: [Locking SDHC Memory card on Samsung Galaxy 2](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17828/) and [How do I secure/encrypt SD card data transparent to apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1940/)

Comment: "Is there an app that does X" questions are generally not a good fit here. (Please see the [FAQ].) I've edited your question to ask for a solution to a problem rather than an application.

Comment: ok, I changed the title to comply with your comment. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many available choices, depending on the features you need:

- [Cryptonite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=csh.cryptonite) uses EncFS and requires root
- [LUKS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nemesis2.luksmanager) also requires root and provides on-the-fly encryption (AES by default) to virtual folders
- [Eds](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sovworks.eds.android) provides encrypted containers and does not require root. It even is compatible to TrueCrypt.
- [DroidCrypt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.atm.android.security.encryption.full) can encrypt single files or full directories. No root needed.
- [Encryption Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.giraone.encmanfull) is a file manager providing file encryption support, and so is [AnDisk](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digitaljoyride.andisk.encryption)
- [FilesCrypter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ua.org.linsalion.FilesCrypter) supports encrypted files and folders

And [many more](https://android.izzysoft.de/catmin/applists/category/named/file_encrypt).¹ Just check the examples, and take a look at the "also recommended" stuff on their market pages to find more.

---

¹ <sub>disclosure: link goes to my Android site</sub>

Comment: Thanks, I will buy and try Eds. It seems to have everything I needed.

Comment: @BehzadMomahedHeravi There's also a [free trial](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sovworks.edslite) available if you want to check it first. Eds looks like the best choice to me as well, though I did not (yet) try any of those apps. Good thing about the TrueCrypt containers is, this way you can even safely store data in the cloud ;)

Comment: Most of these links are dead.  Are there new pages for these apps—were they renamed?  Only EDS and Encryption Manager still have pages at the given URLs.

Comment: @intuited you've noticed that answer is 6 years old? That's half an eternity technically :) May I suggest you check with [my corresponding app listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/catmin/applists/category/named/file_encrypt)? That's kept updated.

Comment: It might be helpful to update answers every half-eternity or so—otherwise they cease to be useful. That link to your app listing doesn't seem to work: it required a name and password.

Comment: @intuited please count the number of answers I've given here. Can't track them all. Core answers I update from time to time, but keeping track of all would be a full-time job. Apart from that: This is not app recommendations. So the apps linked are just examples. Even if the links die, the answer is still valid: There are apps for this, and their names look like that. // Included the link to my corresponding app listing, which (as I already wrote) is kept up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

There's [LUKS Manager](http://nemesis2.qx.net/pages/LUKSManager) which is [available in the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nemesis2.luksmanager&hl=de). It also requires your device to be rooted, however.

It's also [open source](https://github.com/guardianproject/LUKS). I have not tried it myself however, so I can't comment on how well it works.

The closes you can get without a rooted device is probably full disk encryption.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm specifically need an app which works on unrooted devices.